# Scale a pdf vector icon in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, vector

In my project I am using an image asset that is based on a PDF icon:

[image: image-icon]

[image: big-image]

I am now using this image in a `UIButton` but the image takes up too much space. Is there an elegant way to set the size of the image:

Answer (score 1):

Xcode converts PDF image assets to bitmaps at build time, so at runtime you actually aren't dealing with a vector image. Hence you can't actually do perfect scaling. For this reason it's best to have a separate image asset for your button if its size is different.